# Expand sidebar on hover with text

Tags: html, css

I found a sidebar code that I am currently using:

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: black !important;
}

#sidebar a:hover,
#sidebar a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #4caf50;
  color: black;
}

#sidebar a.active {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <center>
  <img width="80%" height="10%" src="https://img.pngio.com/download-for-free-10-png-gold-star-png-icon-top-images-at-carlisle-small-gold-star-icon-png-512_512.png"/>
  </center><br>
  <a href="one.php">1️⃣</a>
  <a href="two.php">2️⃣</a>
  <a href="three.php">3️⃣</a>
</div>
```

I want to add text to the sidebar like this:

```
<div id="sidebar"><br>
    <center>
    <img width="80%" height="10%" src="https://img.pngio.com/download-for-free-10-png-gold-star-png-icon-top-images-at-carlisle-small-gold-star-icon-png-512_512.png"/>
    </center><br>
    <a href="one.php">1️⃣ Number one</a>
    <a href="two.php">2️⃣< Number two/a>
    <a href="three.php">3️⃣ Number three</a>
</div>
```

- But I only want the text to show up when hovering the sidebar. So then not hovering, its a small sidebar with only the symbols, and when hovering, it gets bigger and displays the text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a couple things to get this to work:

1. Wrap the text in an element you can target on `hover`
2. Move the width from the `#sidebar` to the actual `a` element

```css
@keyframes over {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -99em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#sidebar img {
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 3px;
  /* margin: 0 auto;  <-- centers on hover too */
}

#sidebar #nav-items {
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar #nav-items a {
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar #nav-items a span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -999rem;
}

#sidebar #nav-items:hover a span {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: inherit;
  animation-name: over;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#sidebar #nav-items a:active,
#sidebar #nav-items a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #4caf50;
  color: black;
}

#sidebar #nav-items a:active {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <img src="https://img.pngio.com/download-for-free-10-png-gold-star-png-icon-top-images-at-carlisle-small-gold-star-icon-png-512_512.png" />
  <div id="nav-items">
    <a href="one.php">1️⃣ <span>Some text here longer and this is here</span></a>
    <a href="two.php">2️⃣ <span>Some text here</span></a>
    <a href="three.php">3️⃣ <span>Some text here</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When adding a img to the top of the sidebar: `<img width="80%" height="10%" class="imgShake" src="img/pebble.png"/>`, the sidebar fits 50% of the screen, and the image is huge. Why is that?

Comment: Because adding `position: fixed` takes the `#sidebar` out out document flow and relative to the body (with a few exceptions) and not its container. So when you added the img, the side bar is the same width as 80% of your image's native size. In this particular situation, you're better off giving the image a fixed size and `height:  auto` in your CSS. But, you would need to provide more HTML/CSS for your exact case.

Comment: Updated question now :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Also, do not use `<center>` tags. Those are long since deprecated.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But how can I center it without using the `<center>` tags? I've always been using them.

Comment: I used a small margin. If you want the star still centered on hover, add `margin: 0 auto` to the `img` css. Updated with a commented out property.

Comment: To replace`<center>` tags, use `text-align: center` for text/inline elements and use `margin: 0 auto` for block level elements.

Comment: Ok cool! One last question. Why is only the hover text black and other text white? What if I want al the text black?

Comment: What text is white? All the text is black.

Comment: When running your snippet, only the text I hover gets black.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're seeing. The text is black the entire time on my snippet. https://gyazo.com/9fced77b9cfbdc8b871d18d8a62871f1

Comment: I want the `Some text here` text for all items in sidebar to be black and show up all the time when the sidebar is expanded, not only the one that I hover.

Comment: @Andrei I updated my answer to get what you want. I wrapped your nav items in a `#nav-items` div so we can target if the mouse is over that element instead of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar:hover {
  width: 160px;
}
#sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#sidebar a span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#sidebar:hover a span {
  opacity: 0.2
}
#sidebar a:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
#sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: black !important;
  width: 150px;
}

#sidebar a:hover,
#sidebar a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #4caf50;
  color: black;
}

#sidebar a.active {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="one.php">1️⃣ <span>Number one</span></a>
    <a href="two.php">2️⃣ <span>Number two</span></a>
    <a href="three.php">3️⃣ <span>Number three</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer  is nice if all the text is the same width which is a big assumption. You can't guarantee this `width: 150px;` will be accurate.

Comment: @Em an, what about with the image? And the text is not same width, so `width: 150px;` wont be accurate, as @disinfor said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution without any css library or

```css
.navbar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width: 53.8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a {
  padding: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.navbar:hover {
  width: 175px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div style="margin-left:55px;">
  <h2>Hover over the navbar to see the expanding effect</h2>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> about</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
</div>
```

javascript